# Deep learning train large numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When I try to create model to predict this data. I can't get good loss. How can I optimize it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.array([32878265.2, 39635188.8, 738222697.41, 33921812.23, 39364408, 50854015, 50938146.63, 54062184.4, 32977734, 27267164, 30673902.72])
    
y = np.array([80712, 111654, 127836.61, 128710, 147907, 152862, 154962, 138503, 140238, 105121, 113211.8])



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)

scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train.reshape(-1, 1))
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train.reshape(-1, 1))

tf.random.set_seed(42)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  # tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[1]),
  
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=["mae"])

model.fit(X_scaled, y_train, epochs=5000,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

> Epoch 2466/5000 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step -
> loss: 38000588.0000 - mae: 38000588.0000 - val_loss: 28384532.0000 -
> val_mae: 28384532.0000 Epoch 2467/5000 1/1
> [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 38000588.0000
>
> - mae: 38000588.0000 - val_loss: 28384536.0000 - val_mae: 28384536.0000 Epoch 2468/5000 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 38000588.0000 - mae: 38000588.0000 - val_loss:
>   28384540.0000 - val_mae: 28384540.0000 Epoch 2469/5000 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 38000588.0000
> - mae: 38000588.0000 - val_loss: 28384536.0000 - val_mae: 28384536.0000

Comment: You probably need a lot more data than just 11 pieces

Comment: How do you that this is not a good loss? Do you have another baseline model that does it much better ?

Comment: @Lecdi There isn't

Comment: @ManishDash nope, but I should do better

Answer (score 0):

Your NN model is just a linear regression. When you plot the data, you see that you have an outlier which is the main problem for a good prediction:
[image]

I guess, you typed a digit too much.

Comment: Digits should be this

Comment: Then the model will not perform better.